# GitHub sign in authentication code SMS doesn't receive

Tags: github

I wish your help to solve this problem, which is,

Recently, I reset my computer, and I want to sign in again to my GitHub account. In the usual way, when I try to sign in using my user name and password, an authentication code SMS is sent, but it is not sent to my mobile device. The provided phone number is active on my mobile phone.

I wish for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

It happened me too. I waited for few minutes. Then all SMSs came at once. After that I tried to login, then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me at first and then I entered the number wrong (ie. I entered the number with the IDD code in the number input). Then it said the number wasn't valid. Then without refreshing or navigating to anywhere else, I entered the correct number without the IDD code or the leading zeros. That worked instantly.

Not sure what's the real reason. Not sure if this will work for you either. Just commented what worked for me for the record.